# ImageButton skin file scene2d (libgdx )

Tags: libgdx, imagebutton, skin, scene2d

Could anyone point me to a working sample skin file for [Scene2d ImageButton](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/scenes/scene2d/ui/ImageButton.html)? Based on the ImageButton constructor, this was my unsuccessful attempt at creating a basic skin:

```
styles: {
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: 
    {
     down: downImage, 
     up: upImage, 
     checked: checkedImage        
    }   
  }
```

I can't find one anywhere in the documentation, although there is a sample for a TextButton skin file [here](https://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Skins).

In the Libgdx source, there is one example of using an ImageButton in a UI test by setting the styling programmatically [here](http://libgdx.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/UITest.java), but I'm hoping to avoid setting the styling in code.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following skin successfully in my libgdx game:

```
{
  com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.ImageButton$ImageButtonStyle: {
    default: { up: select-default, imageChecked: boundary }
  }
}
```

Where I am referencing the following image resources:

- select-default.png
- boundary.png

Maybe you need to name your style? If anything you can call it "default" and libgdx will use it by default if you don't specify which style to use. Also, I don't have the "styles:" that you have at the beginning. It might help if you could post the specific Exception or error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read [this tutorial](http://code.google.com/p/libgdx-users/wiki/Skins). It is pretty complete and easy to understand.
Basicly, as much as i can remember, you need to define `resources`, which are the Textures etc.
In this resources you describe the name, which is used in your `styles` section (your downImage would be one). You also tell it which region of the TextureAtlas you will use for this `resource`.
Then you have your `styles` section, where you define, which `resource` is used for which `widged` in which situation.
Then in your java code you create the skin, by using the "skin.json" file and the ".png" or whatever file.
But look at this tutorial, it is much more detailed as my quick summary.

Comment: Thank you - I already linked to that tutorial in my question, I used it for TextButtons.

Comment: The same should also work for ImageButtons. Here a more up-to-date Version: (https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/Skin) and another tutorial: (http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2013/12/18/LibGDX-Tutorial-9-Scene2D-Part-3-UI-Skins.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I also worked through the Skin wiki when I was scouring the documentation.  The Skin variations that I based on those examples didn't work for ImageButton.  That's why I was looking for a specific example.